# Printing patterns in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, functional-programming, ascii-art

> Write a function `Int -> Char -> Char -> [String]` that will create the appropriate pattern.
>
> For example: `mapM_ putStrLn (pattern 48 '.' '+')`
>
> ```haskell
> ................................................
> .+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+..+.
> +.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.++.+
> ................................................
> ```

This idea is inspired by [Writing nested for loops to produce certain output](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111932/write-nested-for-loops-to-produce-following-output) (but more general).

I am pretty satisfied with my code to solve this problem:

```haskell
pattern :: Int -> Char -> Char -> [String]
pattern len a b = map (take len . cycle) [[a], [a, b, a], [b, a, b], [a]]

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ putStrLn (pattern 48 '.' '+')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems fine. However, depending on the context and the rest of the program, you can relax `pattern`'s type:

```
pattern :: Int -> a -> a -> [[a]]
```

Also, since every `putStrLn` is basically `hPutStrLn stdout`, you could first glue all lines together with `unlines` and then print them with a single action:

```
main = putStr (unlines (pattern 48 '.' '+'))
```

Comment: I see your suggestions but fail to understand the reasoning about them... why is a general type better? Why is a single action better?

Comment: @Caridorc: The most important parts of the answer are its first two words: __Your code is fine.__ There are just some stylistic choices/alternatives you can consider. However, about the single action: `putStrLn` is basically the same as `puts` in C. From a performance point of view, you try to avoid many I/O calls (I/O, not `IO`) although this _isn't really measurable in this small program_.

Comment: cool performance trick :) What about the general type?

Comment: @Caridorc: You cannot use `pattern 48 1 2` in your original program ^^. The consensus in Haskell is: if you can make a function more general (without loosing something), make it more general. For example, you could define `head :: [Int] -> Maybe Int`. But `head :: [a] -> Maybe a` is a lot more useful.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it to be a text pattern, but it is always nice to know when things could be more general.