# Output Tildes and Pluses

Tags: ascii-art, whitespace-lang

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111932/write-nested-for-loops-to-produce-following-output), I wrote a program in Whitespace to output the following text:

> ```
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~~+~
> +~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~++~+     
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

I left comments in the source code to state what the program does, if I understand the [instructions](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.html) correctly, but I will state the essential parts here as well:

> ```
> IMP           Meaning
> [Space]       Stack Manipulation
> [Tab][Space]  Arithmetic
> [Tab][Tab]    Heap access
> [LF]          Flow Control
> [Tab][LF]     I/O
> ```

The program stars with a space, signified with S, to start a stack manipulation statement.  After the space, I enter the value of a Tilde (126) in binary, with spaces representing 0 and tabs representing 1.  Then, I enter a linefeed (L) to signal the end of the binary character.

Next comes a TL to being an I/O command, followed by SS to output the value at the top of the stack.

This continues on, with the three characters '~', '+', and L (newline).  Is there any way to simplify this either externally or internally?  You can run this program on [Ideone](http://ideone.com).

```
S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L---BEGINS-WITH-SPACE-TO-SIGNIFY-STACK-MANIPULATION-OTHER-VALUES-ARE-BINARY-CODE-FOR-126
T   L---BEGIN-OUTPUT-COMMAND
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L---BELOW-HERE-LINES-NEED-SS-AT-BEGINNING-TO-OUTPUT-VALUE-AT-TOP-OF-STACK
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L---END-OF-FIRST-LINE
S S S S S T S T S L---NEW-LINE(BINARY-CODE-10)
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L---BINARY-CODE-43-FOR-PLUS
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L---END-OF-SECOND-LINE
S S S S S T S T S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S S T   S T S T T   L
T   L---END-OF-THIRD-LINE
S S S S S T S T S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   T   T   T   S L
T   L---END-OF-FOURTH-LINE
S S S S S T S T S L
T   L---EXTRA-NEW-LINE-TO-PUSH-END-OF-PROGRAM-OUTPUT-DOWN
S S L---TRIPLE-LINEFEED-TO-END-PROGRAM
L
L
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know nothing of *whitespace*, but your code strikes me as something like this:

```
...
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("~");
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("~");
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("~");
Console.Write("+");
Console.Write("+");
...
```

You have a *heap*, and you're not using it.

> *Heap access commands look at the stack to find the address of items to be stored or retrieved. To store an item, push the address then the value and run the store command. To retrieve an item, push the address and run the retrieve command, which will place the value stored in the location at the top of the stack.*
>
> <sup>http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.html</sup>

I'm not going to test this, but the idea would be something like this:

- Push 126 ("~") to heap at address A // tilde
- Push 43 ("+") to heap at address B // plus

Now, <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> marks a label, <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> would be a modulo operation, and <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> jumps to a label if the value at the top of the stack is zero: you can implement a form of conditional `goto` loop. And you can call a subroutine with <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, and return to caller with <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>.

Make a subroutine that pushes the value at address A ("~") to the stack, and outputs it before discarding (<kbd>LF</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>) the value at the top of the stack, and then make another subroutine that does the same thing for address B ("-"). Or better, make one that pops an address from the stack, reads the heap value at that address and pushes it to the stack, outputs it and removes it from the stack, then returns to caller. For the purpose of this post let's call this subroutine `PrintChar`.

Now, break down the patterns:

- `~~~~` // pattern A
- `~+~~` // pattern B
- `+~++` // pattern C

Make a subroutine that pushes address A ("~") onto the stack from the heap and calls `PrintChar`, 4 times. Or better, store 4 on the heap at address C and implement a `goto` loop that exits after 4 iterations, and inside that loop you push address A onto the stack from the heap and call `PrintChar`, once; let's call that subroutine `PatternA`. Then, implement similar subroutines for `PatternB` and `PatternC`.

The rest is simple: make a subroutine that pops the address of a pattern subroutine from the stack, makes 12 iterations of calling that pattern subroutine and then outputs a `newline` - let's call that `PrintLine`.

The "main" procedure simply pushes a pattern to the stack and calls `PrintLine`:

- Push the address of PatternA to the stack
- Call `PrintLine`
- Push the address of PatternB to the stack
- Call `PrintLine`
- Push the address of PatternC to the stack
- Call `PrintLine`
- Push the address of PatternA to the stack
- Call `PrintLine`

---

And don't forget to **comment** along the way - I find your commenting not very useful here.